# Organising column labels

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

How do I amke sure that the characters here are laid out neatly?
I have tried using the code `current-window width:40.`
but it doesn't seem to work. I have included a screenshot below.

[image: The code is all jumbled and not precise]

Usually, on other programs, I don't get this problem, so I don't know why it's happening.

Comment: It would be very helpful to show the code that is generating the screen capture along with providing some information about what you would consider to be "laid out neatly" (to my eyes that is fairly neat - but I don't know what you expected to see).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The window width is probably not what you want to be changing. The better option is to work with the frame definition.  For instance:

```
for each customer no-lock:

  display
    custNum
    name
    salesRep
   with
    frame custInfo
    width 60
    side-labels
    1 column
  .

end.
```